# Use the same ID as the button's ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to make it so that whenever I click inside of a div with 
`id="slide$i"` that the clicked div should expand or collapse, depending on current form.

**This a screenshot of how it looks like.**

[image]

So basically if I click in the area of the first div (From Magazijn To Guidion)
it should expand and show additional information. But we'll keep it simple for now and just try to get the divs to move at all.

My code is like this.

```
  $i = 0;
foreach($stock_history as $history){
    echo " 
    <div id='slide" . $i . "' >
        <p>Date: <strong> " . $history->create_date . "</strong> </p> 
        <p>To: <strong> " . $history->toLocation->name . " </strong> </p> 
        <p>From: <strong> " . $history->fromLocation->name . " </strong> </p>
        <p>Moved by:  <strong> " .  $history->user->username . " </strong> </p>
        <hr />
    </div>";
    $i++;
};
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#slide'.$i.'").click(function(){
    if ($("#slide'.$i.'").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#slide'.$i.'").show("slow");
    } else {
        $("#slide'.$i.'").slideUp();
    }
});
```

**Conclusion:**

I want to click a div (id=1 for example) and THAT div should open/close.

Comment: Firstly, use common classes on the elements. Secondly, if the element is `hidden` how will anyone be able to click it?

Comment: Did you make sure to echo that Javascript within your PHP file?

Comment: Oh, I assumed it wasn't. My bad, thanks @odedta

Comment: You're using a counter/iterator inside a foreach loop, this beats the original principal of using a foreach loop, if you're using a counter then use `for` loop :)

Comment: @odedta Correct, I wasn't planning on doing so in the beginning. This was the only idea I came up with to ID the divs.

Comment: is `.is(':visible')` the same as `.css('display') == 'none')` if not, I recommend using display property so you don't have extra (white) space taken. When an element is hidden it still takes space on the page, when it is `display: none;` is it not taking any space.

Comment: @Paramone, your code seems just fine actually, just make sure to `echo <script>YOUR SCRIPT</script>`;

Comment: @odedta I'm pretty sure they're the same. - Alright, will do.

Comment: @odedta Yes, `.is(':visible')` is the same as `.css('display') == 'none')`, but elements with `visibility:hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered visible by the `:visible` selector.

Comment: is fadeToggle() helpful ?

Comment: Oh and a little "By the way", you can use `slideToggle` if you want the additional info to slide up and down on a `click` event.

Comment: @divy3993 It's basically the same as the one I have, just fading instead of moving . But thanks, haven't seen that one yet!

Comment: ok this would be better slideUp() / slideDown() - JQuery plugin.

Comment: @RizkyFakkel Yeah, that is the actual idea behind all this, I was just setting it up and see if this worked in the first place. But yes, eventually there will be some 'invisible' content that'll show when you click on the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class in your divs

```
$i = 0;
foreach($stock_history as $history){
    echo " 
    <div id='slide" . $i . "' class='slide-class'>
    <p>Date: <strong> " . $history->create_date . "</strong> </p> 
    <p>To: <strong> " . $history->toLocation->name . " </strong> </p> 
    <p>From: <strong> " . $history->fromLocation->name . " </strong> </p>
    <p>Moved by:  <strong> " .  $history->user->username . " </strong> </p>
    <hr />
    </div>";
    $i++;
}
```

And JS

```
$(".slide-class").click(function(){
    var current_id = this.id
    if ($("#"+current_id).is(":hidden")) {
        $("#"+current_id).show("slow");
    } else {
    $("#"+current_id).slideUp();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is that you give every slide a generalized classname for the effect and use that as a trigger to [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) additional classes that will handle the actual state of the element.

if every element has a default class of `.product-slide`, you would use jQuery to toggle an additional class:

```
$('.product-slide').off('click.prod-slide').on('click.prod-slide', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('specified-class');
});
```

Then in your CSS you could have `.specified-class` manipulate all the children inside with CSS.

This gives you the freedom to use CSS transitions instead of the much slower non hardware accelerated JS ones ;) (in case of 3d transitions - which you can force anyways)

On the `click` handler you can see my `event` is split by a `.`. This is just event namespacing. Avoiding conflicts with multiple handlers bound to the same element ;)

Hoping this helps you. Good luck!

Comment: I get what you're saying, and totally understand it. However, I've kind of 'figured out' what was going wrong.

These divs have id 0 and 1.

When I look at my script, I see that it wants to target id 2 because of that last i++ made in the foreach loop.

How could I fix this? It should only target the one I'm clicking, instead of getting the highest ID

Comment: How so? $i starts at 0... I'd place `alert('".$i.");` within your loop for testing purposes.

Comment: @odedta I have, it echoes the correct $i in the divs but the output becomes wrong somehow.

Comment: Yeah well, like I said, your code seems fine, try to debug a bit more and if you still don't manage let me know, I can help with TeamViewer.

Comment: At the very last instance of your array in your `foreach`, it will still increment `$i` right? So, if the array has a `count` of 6, meaning 0 to 5 inclusive, `$i` will end up as 6 when it comes out of the loop. Or am I spouting out nonsense? (Just trying to think with you guys)

Comment: @RizkyFakkel Nope, You're correct! That was the issue I had, but it got solved eventually! Thanks for the help guys!